# I want to add data to rdf in Sparql

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to update some data using SPARQL.  Here's the what the original data looks like:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Switzerland#1 >
   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label > "1"@ja ;
   <http://linkdata.org/property/rdf1s2307i#num > "1"@ja ;
   <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#code > "1234"@ja .
```

Here's what I want the data to look like after the update:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Switzerland#1 >
   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label > "1"@ja ;
   <http://linkdata.org/property/rdf1s2307i#num > "1"@ja ;
   <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#code > "1234"@ja ;
   <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#name > "taro"@ja .
```

I've got a query that I'm trying to use, but I end up getting an error back.  Here's the query and the error that I get:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# >
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos# >
PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook# >
PREFIX res: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# >

INSERT DATA{
  GRAPH <http://ddd.test/addressbook> { ab:name "taro" . }
}
```

> SQLState: 22023 Message: SR007: Function exec_metadata needs a string 
>   or NULL as argument 1, not an arg of type ARRAY_OF_POINTER (193)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Don't leave any spaces at the end of your Prefix URIs.
2. When using `INSERT DATA` make sure your statements are in triples. You were using only a predicate and an object.

The above may have been picked up if your had been passing your query through a SPARQL validator before executing.

Try this:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#>
PREFIX res: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

INSERT DATA{
  GRAPH <http://ddd.test/addressbook> {
      <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Switzerland#1> ab:name "taro" .
  }
}
```

Comment: Joshua Taylor-san > I had you repair a dirty writing style, and thank you.

Comment: Anthony Hughes-san > Thank you very much for your precise explanations! It was easy to understand. I appreciate that.